# JS jQuery получить элемент над которым происходит действие

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.t_st_info').ready(function () {
        $( this ).hide();
    });
```

Почему не работает?Элемент не скрывается.

Comment: почему решили, что не работает?

Comment: это задача для css

Comment: Метод `ready` вызывается после того как DOM был полностью загружен. Вам нужен метод `click` вместо ready. Ответ предложенный пользователем **KryTer_NexT** более лучший т.к. в случае динамического появления элемента на странице, метод `click` уже не сработает. Для этого Вам нужен `on` с параметром `click`.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй сделать на событие клика, ну или один из списка, который внизу

```
$('.t_st_info').on('click',function () {
    $( this ).hide();
});
```

- mousedown – нажатие клавиши мыши;
- mouseup – отжатие клавиши мыши;
- click – клик по элементу;
- dblclick – двойной клик по элементу;
- mousemove – движение курсора;
- mouseenter – наведение курсора на элемент, не учитывает на дочерние элементы;
- mouseleave – вывод курсора из элемента, не учитывает дочерние элементы;
- mouseout – вывод курсора из элемента;
- mouseover – наведение курсора на элемент;

Подробнее можешь почитать здесь: [событие *on()*](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: #10комментарий))

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что ready можно использовать на класс. На документ скорее.
Тоесть должно быть что-то вроде:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.t_st_info').each(function(){
         $( this ).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: можно использовать на что угодно, это метод готовности формирования нужного DOM элемента. Зачем писать, если вы даже это проверить не решились, или хотя бы документацию почитать? Ваше `не думаю` мало кому интересно

Comment: "The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted."
Спасибо за Ваше мнение, но как-раз документацию перед ответом я читал.